# TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django

this is views

```
class RegisterView(View):
def get(self,request):
    register_form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request,'register.html',{'register_form':register_form})
def post(self,request):
    register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if register_form.is_valid():
        user_name = request.POST.get("email", '')
        pass_word = request.POST.get("password", '')
        user_profile = UserProfile
        user_profile.username = user_name
        user_profile.email = user_name
        user_profile.password = make_password(pass_word)
        user_profile.save()   #error
        send_register_email(user_name,"register")
```

I want to save user_profile to mysql,But user_profile.save() has an error,
**TypeError: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**，How should I solve it?

Comment: Could you try `user_profile = UserProfile()` instead of `user_profile = UserProfile` and check its output.

Comment: Unrelated, but using a form to sanitize user inputs and not using the sanitized data is asking for trouble. Use your form's `.cleaned_data` to retrieve the email and password instead of getting them from `request.POST`. Or use a `ModelForm` instead...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

you have not instantiated an object of `UserProfile`, instead you are assigning `UserProfile` to `user_profile`

`user_profile = UserProfile`

should be

`user_profile = UserProfile()`